# Why is there no duplicates in pandas dataframe.index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I just wrote a program for college using pandas to structure some unstructured data. I definitely made it harder than it should be, but I ended up finding something interesting.

here is the data I parsed

```
Center/Daycare
825 23rd Street South
Arlington, VA 22202
703-979-BABY (2229)
22.
Maria Teresa Desaba, Owner/Director; Tony Saba, Org. >Director.
Website: www.mariateresasbabies.com
Serving children 6 wks to 5yrs full-time.

National Science Foundation Child Development Center
23.
4201 Wilson Blvd., Suite 180 22203
703-292-4794
Website: www.brighthorizons.com 112 children, ages 6 wks - 5 yrs.
7:00 a.m. – 6:00 p.m. Summer Camp for children 5 - 9 years.
```

here is the (aggressively commented for school)code that is mostly irrelevant but here for completeness sake

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

lines = []

"""opening the raw data from a text file"""

with open('raw_data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

"""removing new line characters"""

for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip('\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=['info'], index=['business type', 'address', 'location',
                                                  'phone number', 'unknown', 'owner', 'website', 'description',
                                                  'null', 'business type', 'unknown', 'address', 'phone number',
                                                  'website', 'description'])

"""creating more columns with the value at each index. This doesn't contain any duplicates"""

for i in df.index:
    df[i] = ''

"""here I am taking every column and adding corresponding values from the original dataframe
extra data frames chould be garbage collected but this serves for demonstration"""

df.index = df.index.astype('str')
df1 = df[df.index.str.contains('bus')]
df2 = df[df.index.str.contains('address')]
df3 = df[df.index.str.contains('location')]
df4 = df[df.index.str.contains('number')]
df5 = df[df.index.str.contains('know')]
df6 = df[df.index.str.contains('owner')]
df7 = df[df.index.str.contains('site')]
df8 = df[df.index.str.contains('descript')]
df9 = df[df.index.str.contains('null')]


for i in range(len(df1)):
    df['business type'][i] = df1['info'][i]
for i in range(len(df2)):
    df['address'][i] = df2['info'][i]
for i in range(len(df3)):
    df['location'][i] = df3['info'][i]
for i in range(len(df4)):
    df['phone number'][i] = df4['info'][i]
for i in range(len(df5)):
    df['unknown'][i] = df5['info'][i]
for i in range(len(df6)):
    df['owner'][i] = df6['info'][i]
for i in range(len(df7)):
    df['website'][i] = df7['info'][i]
for i in range(len(df8)):
    df['description'][i] = df8['info'][i]
for i in range(len(df9)):
    df['null'][i] = df9['info'][i]

"""dropping unnecessary columns"""

df.drop(columns='info', inplace=True)
df.drop(columns='null', inplace=True)
df.drop(columns='unknown', inplace=True)

"""changing the index values to int to make easier to drop unused rows"""

idx = []

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    idx.append(i)

df.index = idx

"""dropping unused rows"""
for i in range(2, 15):
    df.drop([i], inplace=True)

"""writing to csv and printing to console"""
df.to_csv("new.csv", index=False)
print(df.to_string())
```

I'm just curious why when I create more columns by using the name of the index[i] item here

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=['info'], index=['business type', 'address', 'location',
                                                  'phone number', 'unknown', 'owner', 'website', 'description',
                                                  'null', 'business type', 'unknown', 'address', 'phone number',
                                                  'website', 'description'])

    """creating more columns with the value at each index. This doesn't contain any duplicates"""

for i in df.index:
    df[i] = ''
```

doesn't contain any duplicates.

when I add

```
print(df.columns)
```

I get the output

```
Index(['info', 'business type', 'address', 'location', 'phone number',
   'unknown', 'owner', 'website', 'description', 'null'],
  dtype='object')
```

I'm just generally curious why there are no duplicates as I'm sure that could be problematic in certain situations and also pandas is interesting and I hardly understand it and would like to know more. Also, if you feel extra enthusiastic any info on a more efficient way to do this would be greatly appreciated, but if not no worries, I'll eventually read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pandas DataFrame is designed for tabular data in which all the entries in any one column have the same type (e.g. integer or string). One row usually represents one instance, sample, or individual. So the natural way to parse your data into a DataFrame is to have two rows, one for each institution, and define the columns as what you have called `index` (perhaps with the address split into several columns), e.g. business type, street, city, state, post code, phone number, etc.

So there would be one row per institution, and the index would be used to assign a unique identifier to each of them. That's why it's desirable for the index to contain no duplicates.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I'm understanding. So you're saying I could basically have gone "Horizontal" instead where I added all of the columns there, written an algorithm to restructure the data and then inserted it into the correct columns as opposed to the crazy moving around stuff here. Is there a way in this instance I could return my whole "index" with duplicates for learning sake? Ty so much for your time

Comment: Yes, that's it. I'm not sure what you mean by "return my whole 'index'". Note that with `for i in df.index:
    df[i] = ''` you overwrite the whole DataFrame with empty strings. I recommend checking your code line by line, printing the DataFrame each time.

Comment: Thank you. When I initialize the dataframe I specify 1 column named 'info' and on the left hand side of the dataframe instead of using integers to represent rows I use strings that represent what that specific row relates to (my index), then I use that as info to place the unstructered rows into the coresponding columns, then drop the original info column and change the rows to ints. My original 'index' contains duplicates for similar data and when I set each column to be named the same as my index, it automatically dropped duplicates and I was just curious why. sorry for the short story